# JRebel & Docker bean initializing error

Tags: java, spring, docker, jboss

I am deploying my apllication using JBoss running on Docker.

When I run script for building and running image one of beans is still making troubles:

```
ServerService Thread Pool -- 100| ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] 
- Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'applicationValidatorService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'applicationValidator' 
while setting constructor argument; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'applicationValidator' defined in file [/home/exion/.jrebel/cache/ib-validation-ws-impl/deployment/META-INF/spring/ws-applications-beans.xml]: 
    Cannot resolve reference to bean 'poolTaskManager' while setting bean property 'taskManager'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
        Error creating bean with name 'poolTaskManager' defined in file [/home/exion/.jrebel/cache/tasks/deployment/META-INF/spring/tasks-beans.xml]: 
        Cannot resolve reference to bean 'taskExecutor' while setting bean property 'taskExecutor'; 
            nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
            Error creating bean with name 'taskExecutor' defined in file [/home/exion/.jrebel/cache/tasks/deployment/META-INF/spring/tasks-beans.xml]: 
            Cannot resolve reference to bean 'actionExecutor' while setting bean property 'executor'; 

        (...)
```

Here is my bean definition file:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd"
  default-lazy-init="true">
  <bean id="applicationValidator" class="amg.exion.ib.ws.validation.ApplicationValidatorImpl">
    <property name="taskManager" ref="poolTaskManager" />
  </bean>
  <jaxws:endpoint id="applicationValidatorService" implementor="#applicationValidator" address="/appValidator" />
  <jaxws:endpoint id="fundsBlockerService" implementor="#fundsBlocker" address="/fundsBlocker" />
</beans>
```

I have noticed that when I run mvn clean on **ib-validation-ws-impl** and then rebuilded my app this error was not appearing.

Is this error could be related to jrebel cache? If yes then how to clear it?

Comment: Can you provide the end of the exception as that's where the most relevant info lies? It's creating a chain of beans, but `executor` property of `actionExecutor` bean can't be set for some reason, however the error is cut so we can't see where the root cause lies.  

Also there is no "cache" for JRebel spring integration. The .cache folder is simply where classes are kept for remote server setups.

Comment: This is full stack: http://pastebin.com/12MDD8YR

Comment: Root error seems to be
`BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webLogicJmsConnectionFactory' defined in file [/home/exion/.jrebel/cache/ib-jms-notifications-client-impl/deployment/META-INF/spring/ib-jms-infrastructure-beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: JMS_QCF -- service jboss.naming.context.java.JMS_QCF`
Is it correct that the `webLogicJmsConnectionFactory` bean should be picked up(wondering about the weblogic in the name as you run on wildfly)? If not then likely a rebel.xml issue picking up too many files.